# Standard direction format in GIS software

Tags: gis-principle, direction, standards

I am working on an application, where the user can place some items on a map. Some of these items have a direction, currently saved as radians where 0 is towards right/east. We want to enable the user to batch add items via some kind of spreadsheet, and we became unsure if this "0 means towards right" is meaningful. 
When I look at a compass, 0 means towards north.

Do you know if there is an established direction standard in GIS, for example that 0 (radians or degrees) should always mean north (or east)?

Comment: Cartesian angles are in radians counter-clockwise from east, but *bearing* is in degrees clockwise from north.

Comment: @Vince - Not necessarily from east; from the first ordinate's axis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In geomatics (i.e., surveying, cartography and GIS), directions are usually referred to as *bearings* or *azimuths*.

They are almost always quoted in *degrees* for crude measures or degrees, minutes and seconds for precise measures. (Some surveyors in Europe use *gons* where a circle is 400 gons.)

Bearings or azimuths usually start from north and are reckoned positive clockwise, 0° to 360°. In some locales (e.g. USA) surveyors use *quadrant* bearings reckoned clockwise or counter-clockwise from north or south, 0° to 90°.

Sometimes, the terms azimuths and bearings are restricted to refer to soley to one of the two ways of reckoning:

[image]

(Image from [e-education.psu.edu/natureofgeoinfo](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/natureofgeoinfo/c5_p7.html))

Complicating things further, directions may be *true*, *grid* or *magnetic*. (See [applying-proper-conversion-from-true-to-grid-bearing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61743/applying-proper-conversion-from-true-to-grid-bearing).)

As for specific direction types, and especially *formats*, specific GIS software will be slightly different.